# Troubleshooting Landscape Printing Issue in Excel

Tags: excel, windows, printing

I'm facing a challenge with printing an Excel page in landscape mode. When i want to print it as landscape mode all it prints a portrait mode page.

Despite trying various adjustments such as scaling, changing paper formats, and anything related to file and printer properties, I haven't been able to successfully print the entire page in landscape orientation. I've even installed a new version of Windows, but the printing issue persists.

I'm seeking guidance on how to solve this problem, assuming that the sole focus is resolving this printing problem from the ground up. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I tried changing custom scale,paper format kept as A4, also landscape mode kept, playing with page print preview  and anything related to file and printer properties, I haven't been able to successfully print the entire page in landscape orientation

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is off-topic on Stackoverflow. It would be better suited on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com).